# Find matching numbers with prefix and suffix

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table with sample records.

```
CREATE TABLE Testtbl
(
    Number1 int,
    Number2 int,
    AddressA varchar(50),
    AddressB varchar(50),
    originalNumber1 int,
    originalNumber2 int
);
```

Records:

```
INSERT INTO Testtbl VALUES(12345,9876,'A1','B1',9876,12345),
                          (4321,761,'A2','B2',924321,761110),
                          (159,9544,'A3','B3',929544,110159),
                          (158,98714,'A4','B4',110158,9298714),
                          (105,9804,'A5','B5',105110,9804110);
```

I want to find the matching of columnns `Number1`,`originalNumber1` and `Number2`,`originalNumber2`. If it's match then it show the `Number1` values else `originalNumber1`.

The columns `originalNumber1` and `originalNumber2` contains prefix and suffix as shown in the records `92` and `110`.

Expected Output:

```
Num1    Num2
-------------
9876    12345
4321    761
929544  1110159
158     98714
105     9804
```

My try:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN Number1 LIKE '%'+ CAST(OriginalNumber1 AS VARCHAR(20)) +'%' 
                THEN Number1 ELSE OriginalNumber1 END AS Num1,
        CASE WHEN Number2 LIKE '%'+ CAST(OriginalNumber2 AS VARCHAR(20)) +'%' 
                THEN Number2 ELSE OriginalNumber2 END AS Num2
FROM Testtbl
```

Comment: I dont delete my answer cause you didnt inform us about the unknown prefix and suffix, so it might benefit other, BUT Its a good idea next time you write a question that you write that you never will know the prefix and suffix. Thats makes it easier for those who wants to help you. We cannot interpret that out from your question.

Comment: @Thomas, Okay! My bad, I apologies.

Comment: No worries - It was just a heads up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `CASE`

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN OriginalNumber1 LIKE '%'+ CAST(Number1 AS VARCHAR(20)) +'%' 
                   THEN Number1                 
                ELSE OriginalNumber1 END AS Num1,
        CASE WHEN  OriginalNumber2 LIKE '%'+ CAST(Number2 AS VARCHAR(20)) +'%' 
                  THEN Number2              
                ELSE OriginalNumber2 END AS Num2
FROM #Testtbl
```

Comment: I will never come to know the prefix and suffix value's.

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this i think

```
Select 
case when number1 = originalNumber1Clean  then number1 else originalNumber1  end as num1
,case when number2 = originalNumber2Clean  then number2 else originalNumber2  end as num2 

 from (
select *
,case when left(originalNumber1,2) = 92  
          then substring(cast(originalNumber1 as varchar),3,len(cast(originalNumber1 as varchar)))

 when right(originalNumber1,2) = 92     
then reverse(substring(cast(reverse(originalnumber1) as varchar),3, len(cast(originalNumber1 as varchar)))) 

 when left(originalNumber1,3) = 110  
          then substring(cast(originalNumber1 as varchar),4,len(cast(originalNumber1 as varchar)))

 when right(originalNumber1,3) = 110    
then reverse(substring(cast(reverse(originalnumber1) as varchar),4, len(cast(originalNumber1 as varchar)))) 
           else originalnumber1 end as OriginalNumber1Clean


           ,case when left(originalNumber2,2) = 92  
          then substring(cast(originalNumber2 as varchar),3,len(cast(originalNumber2 as varchar)))

 when right(originalNumber2,2) = 92     
then reverse(substring(cast(reverse(originalNumber2) as varchar),3, len(cast(originalNumber2 as varchar)))) 

 when left(originalNumber2,3) = 110  
          then substring(cast(originalNumber2 as varchar),4,len(cast(originalNumber2 as varchar)))

 when right(originalNumber2,3) = 110    
then reverse(substring(cast(reverse(originalNumber2) as varchar),4, len(cast(originalNumber2 as varchar)))) 
           else originalNumber2 end as OriginalNumber2Clean

         from Testtbl
         )x
```